# Outlook onsend addin does not trigger when default encrypt option is send before sending out email

Tags: encryption, office365, office-js, outlook-addin

I have noticed when I select the encrypt option before sending out email, the onsend addins does not work at all. But if i do not select the encrypt option the onsend addin works fine. This is re creatable on the OWA ( Outlook web access) . However, if we encrypt email before sending on desktop the onsend addin works fine.

Any idea on this or has anyone faced this as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior seen on OWA is expected. Add-in does not activate on encrypted emails.  However, in Windows, we have previews that enable Add-ins, including onsend for IRM. Please find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/outlook-requirement-set-preview#add-in-activation-on-items-protected-by-information-rights-management-irm). Note that this requires the Admin to set a custom policy.
On Windows, user can check if Programmatic Access is allowed by right-clicking on the encryption infobar->view permissions and it would say 'Access the message programmatically: Yes/No'

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will try this out.